# What API To use to store documents from an external application

Tags: 2013

We have an external application that creates invoices.
This application generated a PDF of invoices but does not store them

I would like to store them on SP 2013 inside a Document Set.

I need to provide the developers of the other application, a guide in how to connect to sharepoint, how to upload documents, set their properties, etc.

The other app is .net.

What are my options?
REST Services
THe client model (Sharepoint.client.dll)
Web Services.

And what are the advantage or disadvantages of each?

Thanks

Comment: create custom web services and host them on sharepoint server, let other application developer upload document through web services to your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use CSOM (client model) to upload files. REST works, but doesn't give you details about the file you just uploaded. I had to perform another REST call to then get the file to edit it's metadata. With CSOM you have the object in hand, and after the async call you can access the object and its properties easier.

Here's a sample in JavaScript:

```
var oList = currentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(targetLibrary);

var fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
var filePath = targetSiteUrl + "/" + targetLibrary + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName;
fileCreateInfo.set_url(filePath);
fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileData);

var newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);
_context.load(newFile);
_context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    getDocumentListItem(targetLibrary, fileName);
},failure);
```

Comment: can you give me a short sample?

Comment: added example to my reply

Comment: I would also use CSOM. It's an eay API to use and there are many examples on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If the servers that host the application exist on the same network, you could enable the WebDAV and simply tell the application generating the file to drop it on a network path that is a sharepoint list (the same path you would see if you opened the list with windows explorer)

If you need more metadata in the document then I suggest creating a web service or using the lists web service in sharepoint to upload the file. There are a lot of examples out there on how to upload a file to sharepoint via web services and the API is well documented for developers.